# Nginx Client_max_body_size

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to edit the `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`, and according a tutorial I'm following, there should be a `client_max_body_size` under `http {}`, but it's not there on mine. Could it be I'm in the wrong file?

Comment: `client_max_body_size` has a default value of 1 megabyte, so is not necessarily explicitly specified. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#client_max_body_size) for more.

Comment: Should i add the line my self?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Sorry, but your question on the one hand is on the wrong platform (serverfault.com is the right(er) one for this question) and further, it's not very clear (to me), what your problem is. Am I getting something wrong or are you very new to server administration and dealing with config files?

Comment: Well. I kind of wanted to change the client_max_body_size in the nginx.conf file, this was because wordpress wouldn't let me upload certain files. So i opened the nginx.conf file. Normally the line client_max_body_size should be under http { } right? Well in my config file that line was not there. So i was wondering why that was the case. That was basically my question

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.

You have to add this code if its not there:  Client_max_body_size *size*;

Comment: You don't _have_ to add it. You can add it, if you want to change the default value.